# Background size

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Как заставить фоновое изображение уменьшаться, если елемент меньше изображения, и дублироваться в ином случае?

```
background-size: contain;
```

и

```
background-size: cover;
```

не решают проблему ровно никак.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Только js.

Comment: Тогда как это сделать через js, при условии что картинка в base64, да ещё и на клиенте?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так сделать:

```
background: url(/url.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

Будет масштабироваться само, в зависимости от размера!.. Иначе .js //.